# Should I sanitize when using wp_signon() in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `wp_signon()` to authenticate a user:

```
$data = array();
$data['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
$data['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
$data['rememberme'] = false;

$user_login = wp_signon( $data, true );
```

As you can see, I've done nothing to sanitize the user's login and password. I was thinking of doing something like `sanitize_user( $_POST['username'] )` and then maybe something similar with the password but am unsure if this is necessary.

Should I sanitize `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`? If so, I'd be grateful if you could explain why it is necessary in this use-case.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using? I need to know to check the source code and see if there's any validation performed automatically for you. Or you could do it yourself [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/user.php#L26)

Either way, with this things you should always remember to "Trust NO one"

Comment: I'm using 3.9.1. I tried looking in the source at `wp_signon()`, but couldn't see anything associated with sanitization.

Comment: You [can see](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L521) that it uses the `wp_authenticate` function, and if you search that function you can see that it sanitizes the user on the first line and applies a trim to the password.

Comment: I completely missed that. Thanks for pointing it out. Do you want to post your comments as an answer so I can give you some credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb "TRUST NO ONE" but the `wp_signon()` function use the [`wp_authenticate`function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L521), which sanitizes the user and trims the password for you.

Comment: A side note: just "trust no one", without double negative

Comment: @zerkms, that's what you get when you copy/paste. Thanks